# Editable to string Crash

Tags: java, android, crash, android-edittext

I made this code and the program crashes when I try to convert the editable's value to an integer since the texted it type is decimal, and I suspect it's at the point when the application must change the editable to string, due to the fact when the edit text is empty after editing the text it crashes.

```
EditText Y = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.y);
        Y.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(s != null){
                    int Yvalue = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
                }
            }
```

Comment: `Y` is null or `Integer.parseInt` fails

Comment: Maybe use try-catch? try {
   int Yvalue = Integer.parseInt(s);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   // unable to parse
  }

Comment: `Integer.parseInt()` throws a `NumberFormatException` when you provide a decimal point in that `EditText`.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to be able to handle numbers with decimal places (i.e. read them as floating point numbers) or do you want to better handle the error situation?

Answer (score 0):

It looks more likely to me that the NumberFormatException should be occurring while parsing the String to an Integer. Try enclosing it within the try/catch for that exception.

```
 try {
   Yvalue = Integer.parseInt(number);
 } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   Yvalue = defaultVal; // or do whatever necessary
 }
```

Comment: Works perfectly apparently when the edit text can't be converted to float the app crashes unless it's a try. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to parse the value of string to float and get it in float variable

float Yvalue =  Float.parseFloat(s.toString());

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want integers only, try something like this:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

  if (s.length() == 0) {
    // complain about no input
  } else {
    try {
      int yValue = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());

      // ...

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      // complain about invalid input
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not an Android developer, but I'd be surprised if there wasn't a way to add a mask to your input field that prevents anything other than integers being input.